# Screenshot of active window outside borders

Tags: c#, screenshot

I recently found a code to make a screenshot of the active window. It's actually working however the image is a little bit too big, it goes a little bit outside the borders of the current window.

This is the screenshot taken with my program:
[image: this is the screenshot taken with my program]

This is the screenshot taken with alt+printscreen:
[image: This is the screenshot taken with alt+printscreen]

This is my class:

```
public static class Screenshotter
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner  
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner  
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner  
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner  
    }

    public static void MakeScreenshot()
    {
        var foregroundWindowsHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
        var rect = new RECT();

        GetWindowRect(foregroundWindowsHandle, out rect);

        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }

        bmp.Save("test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

I just want it screenshots the active window and not a little bit outside the window. I hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: I'm curious, what's the purpose of `CursorPosition`?

Comment: Oh wow, there's no purpose actually I just see it lol.

Comment: Account for borders dimensions of your window : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Aybe That doesn't give me the size of my active window plus I doubt that class can give me any property of my active window outside my form. I can't find anything with IntPtr and I think the code needs the IntPtr of the window in order to get details from it.

Comment: Just a wild suggestion, try turning off the Aero theme and select a basic theme that doesn't involve any transparency or any fancy blending.

Comment: @RenniePet That's not going to make it better. Even IF it works, then it still has to be fixed as this product is going to be used by other people.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem with the symptoms you have described. In my case, it was due to delay between the moments when a window is registered in system as "foreground" and when it actually fully shown on the screen in front of other windows. You probably observe the same. When you do `g.CopyFromScreen(...)`, you get the pixels from a screen's region that may be still in transition from previous foreground window to the current.
In the first saved image, you can see a screen shot of foreground window (command prompt) made in 150 milliseconds after my image capturing program start:

[image: Screenshot of "foreground" window in with 150 milliseconds delay]

As you can see, it is a mixture of previous foreground window's pixels (Visual Studio) and new one.

It took another 150 ms to fully update the screen:
[image: Screenshot of fully updated foreground window (300 ms delay)]

So, it is not your screenshot has wrong size - it's the new foreground window has not "inflated" yet to its final boundaries.
A simple (and ugly) solution is: insert `Thread.Sleep(...)` before your call `g.CopyFromScreen(...)` to give the system enough time to fully replace the pixels on the screen.